# Modal window presented from viewDidAppear causes main window focus to be lost

Tags: macos, modal-dialog, focus, nsviewcontroller

In my MacOS program, I'm presenting a modal window.  The code is straightforward:

```
class BuyViewController: NSViewController {
    static func showDialog() {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "BuyViewController") as! NSWindowController
        let window = windowController.window!
        let application = NSApplication.shared
        application.runModal(for: window)
        window.close()
    }
    @IBAction func buyAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // Do processing here
        NSApplication.shared.stopModal()
    }
    @IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
        NSApplication.shared.stopModal()
    }
}
```

The code works just fine when I call BuyViewController.showDialog() as a user-initiated action.  But if I call showDialog from my main view controller's viewDidAppear(), then when the user exits the buy window, the main window lacks focus.  Many of the functions on the App menu are grayed out, and the title bar of the main window is light gray.  Clicking anywhere in the main window restores the focus.

stopModal is supposed to return focus to the previous window.  Calling showDialog from the main window viewDidAppear seems to prevent the main window from getting established as the previous window to return to.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I assume window is not fully loaded yet because when i do DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)) in viewDidAppear the focus correctly returns. It might be bug as well.

Comment: calling showDialog  in applicationDidFinishLaunching correctly returns focus. So the issue is your app is not fully loaded (you call NSApplication shared to do modal loop so it needs to be loaded). Alternative is to call presentViewControllerAsModalWindow in viewController so you don't need to wait for nsapp

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Marek.  Moving the call to applicationDidFinishLaunching solves the issue.